# Semantic UI Grid pushing column on blank space

Tags: html, css, frontend, semantic-ui

I am new to semantic UI and I am really confused on how you can push the column in order on the blank space ? 
Can you please tell me how? By the way im using the

```
`<div class="ui grid">
<div class="four wide column"></div>
<div class="four wide column"></div>
<div class="four wide column"></div>
<div class="four wide column"></div>
</div>`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1vh7vz1u/ sample code

here is an image just to show you what it looks like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNsf6.jpg

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @ArunKumarM im sorry but its too long.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the floating you need to use in your code.

Go with following link.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Hope it helps you !!!